# How to get only the git date format as YYYY/MM/DD?

Tags: regex, node.js, git, date, format

Currently I am running: `git log -1 --date=format:"%Y/%m/%d" -- /path/to/file`

It outputs something like:

```
commit 7d1c2bcf16f7007ca900682b025ddf961fd36631
Author: John Smith
Date: 2016/06/16

[maven-release-plugin] some text
```

I only need the date. So far the only way I can extract just the date is by processing the output more with node.js.

```
var date = require('child_process')
    .execSync('git log -1 --date=format:"%Y/%m/%d" -- ./pom.xml')
    .toString()
    .match(/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/)[0];
```

Is it possible to only receive 2016/06/16 via the git command?

Comment: you have several option for achieving what you need or a close by format. read the full answer for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git log -1 --pretty='%ad' --date=format:'%Y/%m/%d'`

`%ad` is author date. If you need committer date, use `%cd` instead.

Comment: `%cd` is very crucial because the commit date is what I need. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to use this:

```
date -d @$(git log -n1 --format="%at") +%Y/%m/%d
```

[image]

You can get a close results with the `--date=iso` format.

for example:

```
git log --date=iso --pretty=format: 
     '%ad%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%aN %s'
```

[image]

Or this one:

```
git log --date=iso-local --pretty=format:'%ad'
```

[image]

Comment: this is pretty cool, I didn't realize there was so many options!